# Double border with only one element

Tags: html, css

I was trying to get a double bordered  (underlined) header. First one is full width, second is just text width. Borders should overlap
There is an easy solution with two elements nested like that:

```
<h1><span>Title</span></h1>
```

and css:

```
h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

h1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Span has `inline-block` display property so it has right width.

I'm wondering if it's possible to get same effect with `:after`, `:before` selectors and only `h1` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It can be done.** I've used [**vw**](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) units.

Take a look at this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/y9vJw/5/)

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="SpecialBorder">Title</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.SpecialBorder
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.SpecialBorder:before , .SpecialBorder:after
{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.SpecialBorder:before
{
    width: 100vw;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.SpecialBorder:after
{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**Explanation:**
the `before` & `after` pseudo elements are the ones that draw the borders.
both of them are empty elements. with a certain width that causes their border to be visible.

they are absolutely position at the bottom of their `<h1>` parent.

`before`: responsible for the red border. so his width is set to '100%' of view port.
`after`:  responsible for the red border. so hes width is set to `100%` of his parent (the `<h1>`), that's why the `h1` is set to `display:inline-block;" (so it will span ony just as his content)

`vw` unit is supported by [new browsers only](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units).

notice that if you cant use `vw` units, you can still make something familiar to that.
delete the `display:inline-block;` from `h1` (causing it to span all the way again)
change the width of `before` to `100%` (to make it span all the way),
change the with of `after` to some fixed value of your choice.

Edit: as *thgaskell* stated in th comment,

> there's a bug where `vw` units don't update properly on webkit
>   browsers when the window is resized.

**Edit 2:**
for making elements to show after the title, you can use a `<br />` tag, or clearing techniques like showed [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/y9vJw/6/).

Comment: An interesting approach, but you should explain how this works and clarify the conditions where it works (browser coverage); “CSS3” is just a collective name for specs and drafts.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Edited my answer with more explanations.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there's a bug where `vw` units don't update properly on webkit browsers when the window is resized.

Comment: @thgaskell didn't know that. +1 for useful comment.

Comment: Damn. Interesting answer but i forgot about one thing. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/M8rwU/
It's still doesn't behave like a normal header.

Comment: @ŁukaszPijet just use a `<br/>` between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you want, but you could do these rules:

```
h1 {
    ...
}

/* here are the direct children of every h1 */
h1>* {
    ...
}
```

`::after` and `::before` selectors would make sense when *inserting* new content (note the double colons). Here's some MDN on `::after` selector and some examples:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: Adding a rule for `h1>*` has no effect if `h1` has no children, and the question was about using just one element.

Comment: But I thought that was the point? If `h1` has no children, how are you supposed to underline the contents? What do you want to underline? It's *supposed* to have no effect in that case. And it is using one element, in a **stylesheet** - it only used `h1` elements. That's what I thought when I first read it. If the author meant using only one element in a document, he could have been more specific, really.