# css under line two color

Tags: css, underline

I am trying to add two different color underline in same text but not able to set 2nd underline its gone down from the first line.

Here is the [link example](http://col323webdesign.com/jeremywalker/when-we-meet) "click here for exmple"
check the title's underline of this ***page Other Meetings*** , ***Church Services***.

```
.zaptitle {
    margin-bottom:20px !important;
} 

.home_widget .page_title_s2, .home_widget .page_title_s3, .home_widget .page_title_s4, 
.page_title_testimonials, .zaptitle {
    border-bottom-color:#EDEDED;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    color:#545454;
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0 0 20px;
    min-height:30px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

And

```
<div class="zaptitle page_title_s2 ">
    <span class="page_info_title_s2" style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(16, 185, 185);">Latest News</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to achieve?

Comment: I did not understand the question. If you want the green underline to shift below, add `padding-bottom`.

Comment: take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949867/double-border-with-only-one-element/18954680#18954680)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add this class

```
.page_info_title_s2{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    min-height:30px;
}
```

this is working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/Hrk8U/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The beauty about CSS is that things don't really have to be like they seem to be. You can create such a line using other elements.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XEGNL/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="hello">hello</div>
<div id="left_line"></div>
<div id="right_line"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#left_line {
    background-color:black;
    margin-right:90%;
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    height:1px;
}
#right_line {
    background-color:red;
    float:right;
    width:80%;
    height:1px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following code in your existing CSS:--

```
.page_info_title_s2{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 line-height: 20px;
 top: 1px;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 }
```

use above code to exact line overwriting. See the working fiddle:--

http://jsfiddle.net/npsingh/RgE2h/1/